# Solving for multiple Nexts

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, modulo, vba

Having trouble unnesting a function that has multiple variables within the loop that needs to change. I have data that is housed into a a few rows but an annoying amount of columns. I am taking the data and stacking it on top of each other so it can be manipulated more. I need a way to change both variables `y` & `n` on the same `next` otherwise it gets stuck into an infinite loop and crashes.

I want the `y`'s to continue on a normal step but need the `n`'s to change with them, otherwise the data is just overwriting and it's repeating itself.

```
Sub pasteanswers()
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim v As Integer



With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 7
        r2s = (LastCol / 2)

End With

For x = 6 To 28
For n = 1 To r2s
For y = 6 To 1721

Cells(y, 8).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * n + 8))).Value
Cells(y, 9).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * n) + 9)).Value



Next y
Next n
Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe get rid of the loop and increment...` n=n+1` before the next y

Comment: this sounds like a good solution! Can you elaborate a bit further or provide a reference of where i can find this information?

Comment: Nothing really to elaborate, if you removed your `n` loop, set `n=0` before the loops and `n=n+1` before the `next y`,"n" would then increase by 1 every time `y` loops.

Comment: the issue with that is that they are different ranges so  `n` would not reset when it needs to

Answer (score 0):

If you need n and y to be equal, eliminate n and use y in it's place. Without example data and expected results, it's hard to test it for you ...

```
Sub pasteanswers()
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim v As Integer

With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 7
        r2s = (LastCol / 2)

End With

For x = 6 To 28
For y = 6 To r2s

Cells(y, 8).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * y + 8))).Value
Cells(y, 9).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * y) + 9)).Value

Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately they are not on the same scale. i'm trying to figure out if an exit for

Answer (score 0):

```
For n = 1 To r2s
    y = n + 5
    If y > 1721 Then Exit For

    Cells(y, 8).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * n + 8))).Value
    Cells(y, 9).Value = Cells(x, ((2 * n) + 9)).Value

Next n
```